# Does the surface $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|} $ have a tangent plane at origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

$f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|} $ is a level set of $g(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$ and now I **claim that partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ exist at zero.**  
$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$ and similarly, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$ and hence $f_x(0,0)=0=f_y(0,0)$

$\nabla g(0,0,0)=(g_x(0,0,0),g_y(0,0,0),-1)=(0,0,-1)$ 
**Hence, equation of tangent plane at origin is:**  $0(x-0)+0(y-0)+(-1)(z-0)=0\implies z=0$

I believe that the above is correct. But I am confused because as per answer sheet, the surface $f(x,y)=\sqrt|xy|$ doesn't have tangent plane at origin. Please help. Thanks.

**Edit: A typo ($f(x, y) =|xy|$ was taken instead of $f(x, y) =\sqrt{|xy|} $) inadvertently crept in in the earlier version of this question and the same has been edited.**

Comment: I know the question is now solved, but you should note that the existence of both partial derivatives does NOT imply differentiability (so it does not imply existence of the tangent plane). On a second note, as mentioned below, you might choose an answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see for $f(x,y)=\left|xy \right|$ your calculation of partial derivatives is correct, and function is  differentiable at $(0,0)  $. And more, partial derivatives are continuous:
$\left(\left| xy\right|\right)_{x}^{'}=\left| y\right| \cdot sgn(x)$.
Also by direct calculation :
$$\frac{\left|xy \right|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leqslant \left|x \right|$$
So it is  differentiable and have tangent in $(0,0)$.

**Note:**
If we take function $g(x,y)=\sqrt{\left|xy \right|}$, then it's possible to calculate,that it's partial derivatives exists in $(0,0)$, but are not bounded: $g_{x}^{'} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left| \frac{y}{x} \right|}$. For differentiablity if we take $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$, then it will be
$$\frac{\sqrt{\left|xy \right|}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So, for $g$ we have not tangent - Your book is correct: Apostol is Apostle.

Comment: You are right. But what about the tangent plane at 0?

Comment: May be typo, mistake.. Or our mistake, which we can't see yet. Can you share source, where is claimed non existence of tangent?

Comment: Please refer Tom Apostal volume 2: Multivariable calculus. Exercise problems 8.17.

Comment: Right now I haven't it, but I'll look necessary - interesting situation.

Comment: @Koro. Do you mean 8.17. -  exercises 6 ? There is $\sqrt{\left|xy \right|}$. This one of course have not tangent. But, please, do not change your question, as answer for it we need for any case.

Comment: Yes. Exercise 6. I think it has tangent. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+plane+to+z%3D%7Cxy%7C+at+%28x%2Cy%29%3D%280%2C0%29. As per this also, z=0 is the plane

Comment: @Koro. No at this one. Added to answer, look, please.

Comment: Oh my God. I typed the question wrong.

Comment: Yes I mentioned it above, but, sorry for repeating, let it, please now as it is. You have twice more then only answer. Ok?

Comment: Thanks. I understood it now. I have found the solution here in problem set 5: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-024-multivariable-calculus-with-theory-spring-2011/assignments/

Comment: Welcome. Now you can choose answer and close question, if  have not something more to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Allawonder's answer is correct, in a more detailed manner, you might see that if you view the graph the surface is $0$ along the main axis, which is the axis you
consider when doing the partial derivative. In other words, the partial derivative
is a directional derivative along the standard basis vectors of your space, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

[image: Graph of |x||y|]

However, a tangent plane, should it exist, can be defined for any choice of basis vectors by taking directional derivatives. If you were to take these directional derivatives for the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ you would immediately run into a problem when trying to apply the formula as you did in your
example. Try calculating
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h, 0 + h) - f(0, 0)}{h},$$
and you should see why you can not have a tangent plane in this point.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. That limit is $h^2/h \to 0$? So how does it imply that no plane can exist?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+plane+to+z%3D%7Cxy%7C+at+%28x%2Cy%29%3D%280%2C0%29. As per this also, z=0 is the plane.